# PHP: How to concatenate NULL to string

Tags: php, string, printf

suddenly my site show new warning -

**The relevant code:**

```
printf ("<input type='text' name='C_Comment' value='" . $myComment . "'  >");
```

**The warning I get:**

- Warning: printf() function.printf: Too few arguments

probably because $myComment is null.

1. I know I Can fix it if I first test if the value is null, and only then conctenate it. but is there a simpler way?
2. Why did not I get this warning before?

Thanks,

Atara

EDIT: sorry, wrong title. The problem was that $myComment was not NULL, it contained special character.

Comment: Why "probably"? Can you not test this with `isnull`?

Comment: "Too few arguments" means number of arguments does not meet the requirement. It has nothing to do with the content in $myComment. Why do you use printf here?

Comment: Looks like you should be using `print` or `echo` instead of `printf` for that - you haven't supplied a format string with arguments, just a string.

Comment: Thank you all for your prompt answers. I am going to change this PRINTF code to ECHO. Can anyone tell me why I did not get this warning before?

Comment: @Atara Because only now have you stumbled upon a comment that contains what *looks like* printf placeholders.

Comment: @Artefaco You were right. I have just checked our DB. $myComment gets the following value: "50% discount"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you get that warning because you don't give enough arguments to `printf`; probably `$myComment` contained printf placeholders like `%s`.

Use `echo` instead if you don't want to use `printf`'s formatting. You can also rewrite your `printf` call:

```
printf ("<input type='text' name='C_Comment' value='%s'>",
    $myComment);
```

Make sure you've escaped special chars in `$myComment` (see [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `printf` just use `echo`:

```
echo "<input type='text' name='C_Comment' value='" . $myComment . "'  >";
```

Answer (score 1):

printf is a function used for formatting a string with given values. You have only supplied one argument to the function, so it is throwing that error in your face.

If you simply wish to print the text on the page, use echo (or just remove the f and use print) with the current string. Or you can do this:

```
printf("<input type='text' name='C_Comment' value='%s' />", $my_comment);
```

[Here's the PHP.net Docs page for printf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php), and you can also view related functions in the See Also section.

Answer (score -1):

Add this before the prinf call if you have a default value (which is not empty):

```
$myComment = ($myComment == null) ? 'yourdefaultvalue' : $myComment;
```

Of course, an echo would do fine also (and than an empty value is no issue anymore):

```
<input type="text" name="C_Comment" value="<?=myComment?>" />
```

Comment: Would have no effect whatsoever. The problem is not the `NULL`, it is the mis-use of `printf()`